# SQL procedure for Archiving and Deleting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedure

I have a requirement for archiving 5 huge tables from PROD to ARCHIVE server without losing the integrity of the tables.

The query makes use of the Linked Server functionality and current idea is to host it on the PROD server. It is a distributed transaction which makes use of Microsoft's Distributed Transaction Coordinator service.

The key requirement is that the PROD server will be live all the time and the performance of the server should not be affected by this procedure being executed.

Tables are as follows:

- header0 - Header
- detail0 - Detail
- email0 - Emails
- overboard0 - Overboard
- references0 - References

Only including the header and detail table in the code for better understanding. Other 3 tables refer the same header tables

1 header may have around 2-4 details detail, 8 messages records and may or may not have records in other tables.

The tables don't have a Primary and Foreign Key Relation in DB as such but have columns that are dependent on header table.

Following is the procedure code currently implemented which is working fine for 18k records and processing 180k+ records in 3.5 minutes of time. Please suggest if this can be improved because going further this table may have 2.5 - 3 million records in a single day.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Compliane_Archive_And_Delete] 
@client nvarchar(8),    -- CLIENT field value
@verbose bit,           -- Set to 0/1 for BASIC/VERBOSE logging
@chunkSize int,         -- Change as per requirement
@historyDays int        -- History Days for deletion
AS
BEGIN

    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    -- DECLARE A TABLE TO HOLD THE KEY VALUES FOR EVERY CHUNK
    DECLARE @NextIDs TABLE(
        cClient nvarchar(8),
        iRunNo  int,
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (cClient, iRunNo)
        );

    -- Hold history days value 
    DECLARE @Xdaysago datetime
    SELECT @Xdaysago = DATEADD(DAY, -(@historyDays), GETDATE())

    DECLARE @chunkCount int
    SET @chunkCount = 0

    DECLARE @procRunDate datetime
    SET @procRunDate = GETDATE()

    DECLARE @MainEventID bigint
    DECLARE @ChunkEventID bigint
    DECLARE @IntermediateEventID bigint

    DECLARE @startTime datetime
    DECLARE @endTime datetime
    DECLARE @rowCount int

    DECLARE @procStartTime datetime
    SET @procStartTime = GETDATE()

    DECLARE @TotalRowInserted bigint
    SET @TotalRowInserted =  0

    DECLARE @TotalRowDeleted bigint
    SET @TotalRowDeleted = 0

    -- LOGGING MAIN PROCEDURE EVENT
    INSERT INTO [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog]
    ([RunDateTime], [Event], [EventDescription], [DBName], [ChunkNum], [StartTime], [EndTime], [TotalTime], [RowCount])
    VALUES
    (@procRunDate, 'START', 'COMPLIANCE_PROCEDURE','ARCHIVE', NULL, @procStartTime, NULL, NULL, NULL)

    SET @MainEventID = @@IDENTITY

    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 [ckhrunn]
                 FROM [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[header0]
                 WHERE [client]  = @client
                   AND [ckhrdte] < @Xdaysago)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION
            -- GET ALL THE RECORDS TO BE ARCHIVED
            INSERT INTO @NextIDs (cClient, iRunNo)
                SELECT TOP (@chunkSize) [client], [ckhrunn] FROM [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[header0] WHERE [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[header0].[ckhrdte] < @Xdaysago
                print 'message '

            -- INCREMENT CHUNK COUNT
            SET @chunkCount = @chunkCount + 1

            -- LOGGING AT CHUNK LEVEL
            INSERT INTO [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog]
            ([RunDateTime], [Event], [EventDescription], [DBName], [ChunkNum], [StartTime], [EndTime], [TotalTime], [RowCount])
            VALUES
            (@procRunDate, 'START', 'CHUNK','ARCHIVE', @chunkCount, GETDATE(), NULL, NULL, NULL)

            SET @ChunkEventID = @@IDENTITY


            -- ################################## ARCHIVING STARTS HERE ######################################### --

            SET @IntermediateEventID = NULL
            SET @startTime = NULL
            SET @endTime = NULL
            SET @rowCount = NULL

            -- ##### COMPLIANCE HEADER TABLE PROCESSING #####

            -- LOGGING AT TRANSACTION LEVEL (THIS WILL BE OPTIONAL IF SET TO BASIC)
            IF @verbose = 1
            BEGIN

                SET @startTime = GETDATE()
                INSERT INTO [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog]
                ([RunDateTime], [Event], [EventDescription], [DBName], [ChunkNum], [StartTime], [EndTime], [TotalTime], [RowCount])
                VALUES
                (@procRunDate, 'INSERT', 'COMPLIANCE HEADER','ARCHIVE', @chunkCount, GETDATE(), NULL, NULL, NULL)

                SET @IntermediateEventID = @@IDENTITY
            END


            -- INSERT INTO HEADER table OF ARCHIVE SERVER's DB
            INSERT INTO [ARCHIVE].[PS_902mssqldev].[dbo].[header0]
            ([client] ,[ckhrunn] ,[ckhsrc] ,[ckhtype] ,[ckhstat] ,[ckhrclnt] ,[ckhrdte] ,[ckhrtme] ,[ckhrusr] ,[ckhcver] ,[ckhprun] ,[ckhcdt1] ,[ckhusr1] ,[ckhusr2] ,[ckhusr3] ,[ckhusr4] ,[ckhactv] ,[ckhuser] ,[ckhdate] ,[ckhtime] ,[ckhwsid] ,[ckhupid] ,[ckhpsl01] ,[ckhpsl02] ,[ckhpsl03] ,[ckhpsl04] ,[ckhpsl05] ,[ckhpslvnum] ,[ckhpslvdte])
            SELECT header.client, header.ckhrunn, header.ckhsrc, header.ckhtype, header.ckhstat, header.ckhrclnt, header.ckhrdte, header.ckhrtme, header.ckhrusr, header.ckhcver, header.ckhprun, header.ckhcdt1, header.ckhusr1, header.ckhusr2, header.ckhusr3, header.ckhusr4, header.ckhactv, header.ckhuser, header.ckhdate, header.ckhtime, header.ckhwsid, header.ckhupid, header.ckhpsl01, header.ckhpsl02, header.ckhpsl03, header.ckhpsl04, header.ckhpsl05, header.ckhpslvnum, header.ckhpslvdte
            FROM [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[header0] AS header
            INNER JOIN @NextIDs AS IDs
            ON  header.client  = IDs.cClient
            AND header.ckhrunn = IDs.iRunNo
            WHERE
                NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1  [client], [ckhrunn] FROM [ARCHIVE].[PS_902mssqldev].[dbo].[header0] AS archiveHeader
                            WHERE archiveHeader.client  = IDs.cClient
                              AND archiveHeader.ckhrunn = IDs.iRunNo)


            SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
            SET @TotalRowInserted = @TotalRowInserted + @rowCount

            IF @verbose = 1
            BEGIN

                SET @endTime = GETDATE()
                UPDATE [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog] 
                SET
                [EndTime] = @endTime,
                [TotalTime] = DATEDIFF(ss, @startTime, @endTime),
                [RowCount] = @rowCount
                FROM [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog] archLog
                WHERE archLog.EventID = @IntermediateEventID
            END


            -- ##### COMPLIANCE DETAIL TABLE PROCESSING #####

            -- LOGGING AT TRANSACTION LEVEL (THIS WILL BE OPTIONAL IF SET TO BASIC)
            IF @verbose = 1
            BEGIN

                SET @startTime = GETDATE()
                INSERT INTO [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog]
                ([RunDateTime], [Event], [EventDescription], [DBName], [ChunkNum], [StartTime], [EndTime], [TotalTime], [RowCount])
                VALUES
                (@procRunDate, 'INSERT', 'COMPLIANCE DETAIL','ARCHIVE', @chunkCount, GETDATE(), NULL, NULL, NULL)

                SET @IntermediateEventID = @@IDENTITY
            END

            -- INSERT INTO DETAIL table OF ARCHIVE SERVER's DB
            INSERT INTO [ARCHIVE].[PS_902mssqldev].[dbo].[detail0]
            ([client] ,[ckdrunn] ,[ckdcat] ,[ckdkey1] ,[ckdkey2] ,[ckdkey3] ,[ckdkey4] ,[ckdseqn] ,[ckdstat] ,[ckdosts] ,[ckdoemp] ,[ckdodte] ,[ckdotme] ,[ckdixml] ,[ckdoxml] ,[ckdrmrk] ,[ckdrusr] ,[ckdrdte] ,[ckdrtme] ,[ckdvid1] ,[ckdvid2] ,[ckdcver] ,[ckdrunb] ,[ckdxdtl1] ,[ckdxdtl2] ,[ckdusr1] ,[ckdusr2] ,[ckdusr3] ,[ckdusr4] ,[ckdactv] ,[ckduser] ,[ckddate] ,[ckdtime] ,[ckdwsid] ,[ckdupid] ,[ckdpsl01] ,[ckdpsl02] ,[ckdpsl03] ,[ckdpsl04] ,[ckdpsl05] ,[ckdpslvnum] ,[ckdpslvdte])
            SELECT detail.client, detail.ckdrunn, detail.ckdcat, detail.ckdkey1, detail.ckdkey2, detail.ckdkey3, detail.ckdkey4, detail.ckdseqn, detail.ckdstat, detail.ckdosts, detail.ckdoemp, detail.ckdodte, detail.ckdotme, detail.ckdixml, detail.ckdoxml, detail.ckdrmrk, detail.ckdrusr, detail.ckdrdte, detail.ckdrtme, detail.ckdvid1, detail.ckdvid2, detail.ckdcver, detail.ckdrunb, detail.ckdxdtl1, detail.ckdxdtl2, detail.ckdusr1, detail.ckdusr2, detail.ckdusr3, detail.ckdusr4, detail.ckdactv, detail.ckduser, detail.ckddate, detail.ckdtime, detail.ckdwsid, detail.ckdupid, detail.ckdpsl01, detail.ckdpsl02, detail.ckdpsl03, detail.ckdpsl04, detail.ckdpsl05, detail.ckdpslvnum, detail.ckdpslvdte
            FROM [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[detail0] AS detail
            INNER JOIN @NextIDs AS IDs
            ON  detail.client  = IDs.cClient
            AND detail.ckdrunn = IDs.iRunNo
            WHERE
                NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1  [client], [ckdrunn] FROM [ARCHIVE].[PS_902mssqldev].[dbo].[detail0] AS archiveDetail
                            WHERE archiveDetail.client  = IDs.cClient
                              AND archiveDetail.ckdrunn = IDs.iRunNo)

            SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
            SET @TotalRowInserted = @TotalRowInserted + @rowCount

            -- UPDATE THE LOG FOR ANALYSIS
            IF @verbose = 1
            BEGIN

                SET @endTime = GETDATE()
                UPDATE [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog] 
                SET
                [EndTime] = @endTime,
                [TotalTime] = DATEDIFF(ss, @startTime, @endTime),
                [RowCount] = @rowCount
                FROM [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog] archLog
                WHERE archLog.EventID = @IntermediateEventID
            END

            -- ################################## DELETION STARTS HERE ######################################### --

            -- ##### COMPLIANCE HEADER DELETE FROM PROD START #####

            -- LOGGING AT TRANSACTION LEVEL (THIS WILL BE OPTIONAL IF SET TO BASIC)
            IF @verbose = 1
            BEGIN

                SET @startTime = GETDATE()
                INSERT INTO [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog]
                ([RunDateTime], [Event], [EventDescription], [DBName], [ChunkNum], [StartTime], [EndTime], [TotalTime], [RowCount])
                VALUES
                (@procRunDate, 'DELETE', 'COMPLIANCE HEADER','PROD', @chunkCount, GETDATE(), NULL, NULL, NULL)

                SET @IntermediateEventID = @@IDENTITY
            END

            -- DELETE HEADER RECORDS FROM PROD SERVER's DB
            DELETE header 
            FROM [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[header0] header
            INNER JOIN @NextIDs IDs
            ON  header.client  = IDs.cClient
            AND header.ckhrunn = IDs.iRunNo

            SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
            SET @TotalRowDeleted = @TotalRowDeleted + @rowCount

            -- UPDATE THE LOG FOR ANALYSIS
            IF @verbose = 1
            BEGIN

                SET @endTime = GETDATE()
                UPDATE [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog] 
                SET
                [EndTime] = @endTime,
                [TotalTime] = DATEDIFF(ss, @startTime, @endTime),
                [RowCount] = @rowCount
                FROM [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog] archLog
                WHERE archLog.EventID = @IntermediateEventID
            END

            -- ##### COMPLIANCE DETAIL DELETE FROM PROD START #####

            -- LOGGING AT TRANSACTION LEVEL (THIS WILL BE OPTIONAL IF SET TO BASIC)
            IF @verbose = 1
            BEGIN

                SET @startTime = GETDATE()
                INSERT INTO [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog]
                ([RunDateTime], [Event], [EventDescription], [DBName], [ChunkNum], [StartTime], [EndTime], [TotalTime], [RowCount])
                VALUES
                (@procRunDate, 'DELETE', 'COMPLIANCE DETAIL','PROD', @chunkCount, GETDATE(), NULL, NULL, NULL)

                SET @IntermediateEventID = @@IDENTITY
            END

            -- DELETE DETAIL RECORDS FROM PROD SERVER's DB
            DELETE detail
            FROM [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[detail0] detail
            INNER JOIN @NextIDs IDs
            ON  detail.client  = IDs.cClient
            AND detail.ckdrunn = IDs.iRunNo

            SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
            SET @TotalRowDeleted = @TotalRowDeleted + @rowCount            

            -- UPDATE THE LOG FOR ANALYSIS
            IF @verbose = 1
            BEGIN

                SET @endTime = GETDATE()
                UPDATE [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog] 
                SET
                [EndTime] = @endTime,
                [TotalTime] = DATEDIFF(ss, @startTime, @endTime),
                [RowCount] = @rowCount
                FROM [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog] archLog
                WHERE archLog.EventID = @IntermediateEventID
            END


            -- UPDATE THE LOGGING FOR MAIN PROCEDURE EVENT

            SET @endTime = GETDATE()
            UPDATE [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog]
            SET
            [EndTime] = @endTime,
            [TotalTime] = DATEDIFF(ss, @procStartTime, @endTime),
            [RowsCreatedCount] = @TotalRowInserted,
            [RowsDeletedCount] = @TotalRowDeleted
            FROM [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[ArchiveLog] archLog
            WHERE archLog.EventID = @MainEventID

            DELETE FROM @NextIDs

            COMMIT
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        print 'catch'               
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK

            SET NOCOUNT ON 
            INSERT INTO [ARCHIVE].[PS_902mssqldev].[dbo].[ErrorLog]
                (ErrorNumber, ErrorDescription, ErrorProcedure, ErrorState, ErrorSeverity, ErrorLine, ErrorTime)
            VALUES
                (ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_LINE(), GETDATE());
            SET NOCOUNT OFF
        END CATCH;

    END /* IF / WHILE */
END;
GO

--RUN PROCEDURE
--exec usp_Compliane_Archive_And_Delete 'SYS', 1, 5000, 14
```

This will run in a chunk of 5000 records which can be controlled from the input parameter.

Some logging is also implemented in order to track time taken and other information.

Please suggest if this is a good design as per the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Nitpicks

You use separate statements for `DECLARE` and `SET` quite a bit. While there is nothing wrong with that, it's often just easier to read if you combine them:

```
DECLARE @Xdaysago datetime = DATEADD(DAY, -(@historyDays), GETDATE());
DECLARE @chunkCount int = 0;
DECLARE @procRunDate datetime = GETDATE();
```

---

You made this comment in your post:

> This will run in a chunk of 5000 records which can be controlled from the input parameter.

If you know that your default value is 5000, consider setting it as default value in your procedue signature (hence making the parameter optional). You could also do this for `@verbose` if you expect to run it with one of the two settings more often than not. In both cases, the params would only then need to be provided if the caller decided to not use the provided default values.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Compliane_Archive_And_Delete] 
    @client nvarchar(8),    -- CLIENT field value
    @historyDays int,       -- History Days for deletion
    @chunkSize int = 5000,  -- Change as per requirement
    @verbose bit = 0        -- Set to 0/1 for BASIC/VERBOSE logging
AS ...
```

*Note I changed the order a bit to make the optional parameters last.*

---

It's a good habit to terminate your statements with semicolon `;` even though Microsoft T-SQL is not strict at the moment. It is the ANSI standard and as far as I am aware Microsoft is the only RDBMS that does not enforce this yet.

According to MSDN (emphasis mine):

> Transact-SQL statement terminator.Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, **it will be required in a future version.**

References:

- [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx) - MSDN
- [Always Use Semicolon Statement Terminators](http://www.dbdelta.com/always-use-semicolon-statement-terminators/) - Dan Guzman's Blog

---

Lines like these should be shortened to make reading easier (and avoid making mistakes like mixing up column counts):

> ```
> INSERT INTO [ARCHIVE].[PS_902mssqldev].[dbo].[header0]
> ([client] ,[ckhrunn] ,[ckhsrc] ,[ckhtype] ,[ckhstat] ,[ckhrclnt] ,[ckhrdte] ,[ckhrtme] ,[ckhrusr] ,[ckhcver] ,[ckhprun] ,[ckhcdt1] ,[ckhusr1] ,[ckhusr2] ,[ckhusr3] ,[ckhusr4] ,[ckhactv] ,[ckhuser] ,[ckhdate] ,[ckhtime] ,[ckhwsid] ,[ckhupid] ,[ckhpsl01] ,[ckhpsl02] ,[ckhpsl03] ,[ckhpsl04] ,[ckhpsl05] ,[ckhpslvnum] ,[ckhpslvdte])
> SELECT header.client, header.ckhrunn, header.ckhsrc, header.ckhtype, header.ckhstat, header.ckhrclnt, header.ckhrdte, header.ckhrtme, header.ckhrusr, header.ckhcver, header.ckhprun, header.ckhcdt1, header.ckhusr1, header.ckhusr2, header.ckhusr3, header.ckhusr4, header.ckhactv, header.ckhuser, header.ckhdate, header.ckhtime, header.ckhwsid, header.ckhupid, header.ckhpsl01, header.ckhpsl02, header.ckhpsl03, header.ckhpsl04, header.ckhpsl05, header.ckhpslvnum, header.ckhpslvdte
> FROM [PS_902mssqldev_prod].[dbo].[header0] AS header
> ```

Consider adding line breaks every N columns on both the `INSERT INTO` and `SELECT` statements to make it more legible and having to scroll horizontally to see the whole statement.

---

You can use `+=` and `-=` operators in `SET` statements (like increments within loops, etc.) as you can in many other languages:

> ```
> SET @TotalRowInserted = @TotalRowInserted + @rowCount;
> ...
> SET @chunkCount = @chunkCount + 1;
> ```

Become simply:

```
SET @TotalRowInserted += @rowCount;
...
SET @chunkCount += 1;
```

---

## Performance

For the most part, this is pretty straightforward and there may not be huge performance gains to be made, but I spotted a few things that potentially could help some.*

<sub>* Your mileage may vary.</sub>

---

#### Transaction isolation level

There is no declared isolation level in your procedure. How could it impact performance? Well, it depends. The database probably has a default isolation level for read operations, you should definitely check that.

You may or may not be worried about uncommitted reads (a.k.a. "ghost reads"), and this would primarily be for the `INSERT INTO @NextIDs` as far as I can tell, but it could alleviate potential locks on the production database.

Reference: [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) - MSDN

Another small improvement might be to `SET NOCOUNT ON` for the whole procedure, rather than just at the end in your `CATCH` block.

---

#### "Physical" temporary table

This:

> ```
> DECLARE @NextIDs TABLE(
>     cClient nvarchar(8),
>     iRunNo  int,
>     UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (cClient, iRunNo)
>     );
> ```

... might be better off as a "physical" `#NextIDs` temp table on disk, instead of an in-memory table. This of course can vary depending on the memory and I/O capabilities of the server(s), as well as which version of SQL Server you are using and so on. I can just say that from my own experience at least, `#TempTable` are almost always faster than `@TempTable` when used for any non-trivial amount of records. This also lets you control indexing and things like that, while the temp table exists.

Some references on the topic:

- [Special Table Types](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - Microsoft TechNet

*This one is really good:*

- [Are Table Variables as Good as Temporary Tables in SQL 2014?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/04/table-variables-good-temp-tables-sql-2014/) - Kendra Little, BrentOzar.com
- [Optimizing Performance / Indexes on Temp Tables](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/optimizing-performance-indexes-on-temp-tables) - Bill Richmond, SQLTeam.com

---

#### Ask a DBA!

Database Administrators have some unique and privileged insights in regards to database performance, specifications and such. In addition to consulting your internal DBA(s), there is also a [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange site where you could get more advanced advice (although this question as it is would not be good there - read their FAQ [What topics can I ask about here?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) if you decide to ask a question there.

Comment: As an extra temporary tables support indexes, we don't have enough info on the table definitions and execution plans to say anything about efficiency but that could be an added bonus, that could be emphasized more

Comment: @PinCrash It was a great and thorough analysis of the procedure and can't thank you enough for all the points you have covered. Just a couple of questions I had in mind:

Comment: @PinCrash It was a great & thorough analysis of the procedure and can't thank you enough for all the points covered. Thanks for pointing out `SET NOCOUNT ON` My bad.  
  
Just a couple of questions I had in mind:  
1. What do you mean when you say, * Your mileage may vary?  
2. What database should be in use when these #Tables should be created?  
3. Any specific suggestion regarding deletion of the records?  

Also, now while inserting in archive select statements we now use `with(nolock)` hint. This is because we  are dealing with history records and should'nt cause dirty reads.

Comment: (1) What I meant by that is some database setups may benefit from some of those things, while some others may not, depending on a whole range of different factors that make each individual database server different from others

Comment: (2) When I have used #TempTables in queries that involved linked servers, I have created them on the source or "starting" server, but those were very different type of queries (running selects in a cursor over _N_ linked servers to gather some data from each to a central location). In your case, I think it might be better to create them on the archive server as it doesn't seem as "critical" for it to have no performance slowdowns while archiving, although I would suggest to test both.

Comment: (3) No specific suggestions for deletes that wouldn't apply to other "write" operations. In cases where you may have a large amount of writes to make on a table and it's more important to avoid potential escalated locks than to run the job quicker, it can be a good idea to make "trickle" updates/deletes using a loop.

Comment: @PinCrash Thanks for clarifying on all the points. I happily want to inform that from initial tests the above procedure took ~ 1.91 hours to archive and delete 3 million records (collectively for the 5 tables involved). This was done simultaneously when Data Load + Application was being used. It was done over a Linked Server on the same Local Area Network. Both server had 8GB of memory installed with a 6 core cpu (maxdop set to 4 cores). I am accepting your answer as the chosen one. Thanks for everything. May bother you if need some more inputs in future which this script is live :)

Comment: @AmanS.Aneja Great! Out of curiosity, did you run it with 3million `@chunkSize` instead of 5000, or did you run it for 5000 chunk size at a time until it had processed all of them? Also was that running in verbose mode or not?

Comment: @PinCrash Sorry for missing out on that detail. We started with 5 million records in the PROD. First we tried with a chunk of 10000 and it took ~300 seconds per chunk, processing a little over 120k records in every chunk. We reduced to 5000 in by stopping the script in the middle and found that it took ~100 seconds which processed 60-70k records. We again stopped the script to see the trend and reduced it to 2500 and then 1000, this took an average of 44~50 seconds and 16~20 seconds respectively. 2 million records were already transferred in all these runs. To be Continued..

Comment: @PinCrash ..Continued! Once we saw that the 1000, 2500 and 5000 chunks bring near about similar performance. We went with the 1000 per chunk and then waited to get all the records processed. It took 1.91 hours to process these remaining 3 million records while archive was already having 2 million records present in the DB, and PROD was continuously growing with the Load tests being performed (this didn't affect us because we ran it for all the records created 1 day prior). The record count was expected, there was no data loss and yes we ran each and every test with `@verbose` flag set to 1.